# Scale x axes in ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I have list of data which I visualize by using `ListContourPlot`.

```
data = Table[RandomReal[i]*RandomReal[j], {i, 5}, {j, 6}];  

ListContourPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: ListContourPlot]

Each column of data correspondes to a segment which has a certain length. For example:

```
segments = {{0, 5}, {5, 12}, {12, 27}, {27, 32}, {32, 35}, {35, 40}}
```

Now I would like to rescale the x axes so that the columns have the right length in the plot. If possible also the caption of the x axes should match.

-Frink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably solve the problem by giving explicit *x*, *y*, *z* coordinates for the data. In your case, I would first define the *x* position based on your segments:

```
pos = Mean /@ segments;
```

Then we can create a dataset that consists of 5 rows and 6 columns, but where the position of each column is defined by the above pos:

```
newdata = Join @@ Table[{pos[[i]], j, RandomReal[i]}, {j, 5}, {i, 6}];
```

The `ListContourPlot` with the *x*-axis specified by using `FrameTicks`:

```
ListContourPlot[newdata, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Union @@ segments, None}}]
```

[image: ListContourPlot]

**Update**

To add some strings that contain information about the single segments you might do this:

```
ListContourPlot[newdata, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
  None}, {Join @@ {Transpose[{Union @@ segments, 
  Union @@ segments}], 
  Transpose[{pos, {"Seg.1", "Seg.2", "Seg.3", "Seg.4", "Seg.5", 
  "Seg.6"}}]}, None}}]
```

[image: ListContourPlot]

At this point, I've noticed that it would be better to add some data points at *x* values of 0 and 40 to define the exact range of your plot. These additional data points have a *z*-value equal to 0.

```
newdata2 = Join[newdata, Transpose[{Table[0, {5}], Range[5], Table[0, {5}]}], 
  Transpose[{Table[40, {5}], Range[5], Table[0, {5}]}]];

ListContourPlot[newdata2, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
  None}, {Join @@ {Transpose[{Union @@ segments, 
  Union @@ segments}], 
  Transpose[{pos, {"Seg.1", "Seg.2", "Seg.3", "Seg.4", "Seg.5", 
  "Seg.6"}}]}, None}}]
```

[image: ListContourPlot]

Comment: I was about to post an answer but I like yours better.  Do you mind if I make a few changes?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Building on VLC's answer, to convert existing data you might do something like this:

```
SeedRandom[14];
data = Table[RandomReal[i]*RandomReal[j], {i, 5}, {j, 6}];

ListContourPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
segments = {{0, 5}, {5, 12}, {12, 27}, {27, 32}, {32, 35}, {35, 40}};

pos = Mean /@ segments;

data2 = Join @@ MapIndexed[{pos[[#2[[2]]]], #2[[1]], #} &, data, {2}];

ListContourPlot[data2, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 700, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Union @@ segments, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: big thank you @VLC and Mr.Wizard. It works really perfect. There is one thing in addition which I would like to do with the plot. I have a list of Strings which contains some facts about each of the segments. For example: '{"Seg.1","Seg.2","Seg.3","Seg.4","Seg.5","Seg.6"}'. Is it possible to write this information at the right posizion under the plot (or directly into the plot)?. -Frink

Comment: @Frink See my update.

Comment: @VLC thx for your updates, looks nice and works fine!

Comment: one further question: Is it possible the take the values constant for each segment? -Frink

Comment: @Frink unless your last comment is addressing me you forgot `@VLC`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you are right thx you for the clue.

Comment: @VLC is there a possibilty to keep the values constant for each segment?

Comment: @Frink To which values are you referring to? If you provide an example, it might be clearer. Just update your question.